# Hardness of node partitioning under shortest path constraint

Tags: graph-theory, np-hardness

Given a direct graph $G=(V,E)$. $\forall (i,j) \in E$, there is a weight $w(i,j) \in R$ (negative weight is possible). A label $l(i)$ is associated with each node $i \in V$. How to assign $k$ (or less) distinctive values to $l(i)$ such that
$$l(j) \leq l(i) + w(i,j),\quad \forall (i,j) \in E ?$$
Notice that when $k=|V|$, this problem is easily solvable by Shortest path algorithm (Bellman-Ford). But what's the hardness is this problem for $k < |V|$?

Comment: Could you explain how you solve the case where $k=|V|$?

Comment: indeed. Unless you can guarantee that w does not induce negative cycles, you might have a problem.

Comment: @Suresh: I do not think that negative cycles are problem because if w has is a negative cycle, we know that there are no solutions.

Comment: @serge if $k=|V|$, we can run Bellman-Ford, the algorithm gives $l(i)$ for all $i \in V$ upon termination. Or, like what @Ito said, detects a negative cycle, indicating no solution. Oh, There might be a problem if in the result, there's $l(i)=l(j)$ for some $i \neq j$. In this case we get the solution for some $k < |V|$. Yes, that's a problem...

Comment: @Serge I slightly modify the definition of the problem, asking for $k$ or less distinctive groups.

Comment: If k=|V|−1, you can try all the $\binom{|V|}{2}$ possibilities of making two labels equal, and therefore the problem can be solved in polynomial time.  The same holds for the case where k=|V|−O(1).

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the problem formulation right: If the weights are nonnegative, then you can simply assign the label 0 to all nodes? Hence the problem is interesting only if you have negative weights; and with negative weights, the problem makes sense only if your graph is *directed*?

Comment: @Jukka: I assumed implicitly that the input graph was directed, but I agree that it is better to make it explicit if that is the case.

Comment: @Jukka @turkistany and @Tsuyoshi Yes. The graph is directed and admits negative weight. Otherwise the problem is trivial. Sorry, I didn't make it clear at first. I edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s call an assignment of vertex labels *feasible* if it satisfies all the inequality constraints, ignoring the condition on the number of distinct labels.

Here is what I think is a proof that it is NP-complete to decide whether a given directed graph *G*=(*V*, *E*) with integer (possibly negative) edge weights has a feasible assignment of labels which uses at most *k* distinct labels, for *k*=|*V*|/2.  We construct a reduction from the following NP-complete problem [WY92].

Equal Subset Sum
*Instance*: A finite set *S* of positive integers.
*Question*: Do there exist two disjoint nonempty subsets *S*<sub>1</sub> and *S*<sub>2</sub> of *S* whose sums are equal to each other?

Let *S*={*a*<sub>1</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*n*</sub>} be a set of positive integers, where *n*=|S|.  Construct a directed graph *G* with 2*n* vertices *u*<sub>1</sub>, …, *u*<sub>*n*</sub>, *v*<sub>1</sub>, …, *v*<sub>*n*</sub> by connecting *u*<sub>*i*</sub> and *v*<sub>*i*</sub> in both directions for each *i*.  Give the weight *a*<sub>*i*</sub> to the edge (*u*<sub>*i*</sub>, *v*<sub>*i*</sub>) and −*a*<sub>*i*</sub> to the edge (*v*<sub>*i*</sub>, *u*<sub>*i*</sub>).

Consider the instance (*G*, *n*) of the current problem.  Note that an assignment *l* of labels is feasible if and only if for each *i*, it holds *l*(*v*<sub>*i*</sub>)=*l*(*u*<sub>*i*</sub>)+*a*<sub>*i*</sub>.  From this, we can prove the following, establishing that the above transformation is a reduction from Equal Subset Sum to the current problem.

**Claim**.  *G* has a feasible assignment which uses at most *n* distinct labels if and only if there exist two disjoint nonempty subsets *S*<sub>1</sub> and *S*<sub>2</sub> of *S* whose sums are equal to each other.

**Proof**.  First observe that if we are given a feasible assignment *l* (which might use any number of distinct labels), we can construct a directed graph *H*<sub>*l*</sub> from *G* by removing the edges with negative weights and merging vertices with equal labels.  Note that *H*<sub>*l*</sub> has exactly *n* edges whose weights are *a*<sub>1</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*n*</sub>.  Also, note that the number of vertices of *H*<sub>*l*</sub> is equal to the number of distinct labels used in *l*.

For the “only if” direction, given a feasible assignment *l* which uses at most *n* distinct labels, consider the directed graph *H*<sub>*l*</sub>.  Since *H*<sub>*l*</sub> has at most *n* vertices and exactly *n* edges, *H*<sub>*l*</sub> contains a cycle *C* ignoring the direction of edges.  Let *S*<sub>1</sub> be the set of weights of edges appearing in *C* in one direction, and *S*<sub>2</sub> be the set of weights of edges appearing in *C* in the other direction.  It is easy to see that the sum of *S*<sub>1</sub> is equal to the sum of *S*<sub>2</sub>.

For the “if” direction, fix *S*<sub>1</sub> and *S*<sub>2</sub> be the subsets of *S* satisfying the condition.  Without loss of generality, assume that *S*<sub>1</sub>={*a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*s*</sub>} and *S*<sub>2</sub>={*a*<sub>*s*+1</sub>, *a*<sub>*s*+2</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*s*+*t*</sub>}, where *s*=|*S*<sub>1</sub>| and *t*=|*S*<sub>2</sub>|.  Then we assign the following labels to the vertices of *G*:

- *l*(*u*<sub>1</sub>)=*l*(*u*<sub>*s*+1</sub>)=0.
- *l*(*u*<sub>*i*</sub>)=*l*(*v*<sub>*i*−1</sub>) for 2≤*i*≤*s* and *s*+2≤*i*≤*s*+*t*.
- *l*(*u*<sub>*i*</sub>)=0 for *s*+*t*+1≤*i*≤*n*.
- *l*(*v*<sub>*i*</sub>)=*l*(*u*<sub>*i*</sub>)+*a*<sub>*i*</sub> for 1≤*i*≤*n*.

It is easy to verify that this assignment is feasible and uses at most *n* distinct labels.  (The graph *H*<sub>*l*</sub> in this case consists of two edge-disjoint paths from the vertex labeled 0 to the vertex labeled $\sum_{i=1}^s a_i = \sum_{i=s+1}^{s+t} a_i$ and *n*−*s*−*t* edges originating at the vertex labeled 0.)  **QED**.

References

[WY92] Gerhard J. Woeginger and Zhongliang Yu.  On the equal-subset-sum problem.  *Information Processing Letters*, 42(6):299–302, July 1992.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(92)90226-L

Comment: What does "identifying vertices with equal labels" mean? Are they merged?

Comment: @Kid: Yes, they are merged.  I changed the wording in the answer.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, Is Equal Subset Sum strongly NP-complete?

Comment: @turkistany: Good question.  The answer is no (unless P=NP), because if the integers in the input are given in unary, you can compute the number $b_t$ of subsets summing up to t by simple dynamic programming.  The answer to Equal Subset Sum is yes if and only if some t in the range $0\le t\le\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ satisfies $b_t>1$.  It seems that the problem in the question is also likely to have a pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm based on dynamic programming (assuming that the numbers in the input are integers), but I have not given much thought to it.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi I'm also curious about whether this problem is strongly NP-complete. Though it is reduced from equal subset sum, which is weakly NP-complete, but the graph constructed is quite specialized (with $n/2$ pair of disjoint component and zero cycles between them). For general graph structure, it seems to be much more complicated.

Comment: @Kid: Sounds like a candidate for a separate question.  The pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm I had in mind seems to work only in the case where k is a constant, and I am no longer sure whether the current problem has a pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm or not.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi What do you mean by "k is a constant"? I modified the original question to further discuss the hardness of this problem. You answer above is still valid.

Comment: @Kid: I think that you should have posted a separate question, linking to this question (partly because I think that the original question was already answered, partly because my answer is too long).  As for k being constant, the algorithm I was thinking about runs in time $O(((|V|+|E|)S)^k)$ (or something like that), where S is the sum of the absolute values of weights of all edges, assuming all weights are integers.  It is pseudo-polynomial-time only if k is a constant, not something like k=|V|/2.

Comment: @Kid: As for whether to post a separate question or edit a question, you may want to ask the opinions of other people.  In that case, please post a question on [meta](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/), linking to this question.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Thanks. I started a new post about this question.