# Further question on hardness of node partitioning under shortest path constraint

Tags: graph-theory, np-hardness

This question first appeared at [Hardness of node partitioning under shortest path constraint](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1555/1351) and I restate it here

> Given a direct graph $G=(V,E)$. $\forall (i,j) \in E$, there is a weight $w(i,j) \in \mathbb{Z}$ (integer and negative weight is possible). A label $l(i)$ is associated with each node $i \in V$. How to assign $k$ (or less) distinctive values to $l(i)$ such that
>   $$l(j) \leq l(i) + w(i,j),\quad \forall (i,j) \in E ?$$
>   Notice that when $k=|V|$, this problem is easily solvable by Shortest path algorithm (Bellman-Ford). But what's the hardness is this problem for $k < |V|$?

@Tsuyoshi has proved this problem to be **NP-complete** in the original post. Although the reduction is from a weakly NP-complete problem "equal subset sum", the problem listed above seems to be more complicated. So my further question is **whether this problem is strongly or weakly NP-complete**?

Comment: (1) Are edge weights integers?  If so, please state it in the question.  (2) There seem to be several excessive “>” symbols in the question.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi the edge weights are integer. I edited the problem.

Comment: You added the tag [approximation-hardness].  Can you elaborate on how this question is related to hardness of approximation, preferably in the question?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi If the problem is strongly NP-complete, there's no pseudo-polynomial or FPTAS algorithm.

Comment: When you say FPTAS, which optimization problem are you talking about?

Comment: Currently I have no idea about this..

Comment: Then I do not think that you should tag the question as [approximation-hardness].  If/when you are sure that the question is related to hardness of approximation, it will be helpful to state the relation in the question and add the tag.

Comment: Ok. Let me remove it.

Comment: Presumably the relevant parameter is k, but since this is integral, you can't get an FPTAS anyway